# How to pass file name to sed

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I'm trying the following

```
grep 178 * | sed 's/178/179/g'

Results:

ifcfg-bond0:IPADDR=10.30.10.179
ifcfg-bond1:IPADDR=10.30.8.179
rule-bond0:from 10.30.10.179 table sip
```

However when I try to pass -i option to sed to make changes permanent, I get the following.

```
grep 178 * | sed -i 's/178/179/g'
sed: no input files
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With `grep 178 *` you are selecting all files in current directory. You have to get a specific one in order to do `sed ... file`.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I got it to work! :)

```
 grep -rl 178 ../network/ | xargs sed -i 's/178/179/g'
```

Comment: Funny how we solve a problem just seconds after we wrote it up for someone else :-)

Answer (score 2):

What about avoiding a fork/pipe with

```
 sed -i 's/178/179/g' *
```

Files that don't contain 178 won't be affected.

The original in your question can't work because `-i` replaces *files* in-place, but you pipe the data in via stdin (for which in-place substituion just makes no sense).

Comment: but they will be re-written so the mtime will be "now". That may be an unintended side effect.

Comment: Very goed efficient solution. @Glenn The side effect is not an issue (not specified as a constraint in question and normal effect).